# jQuery: Cache reference of created DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Look at following hypothetic code:

```
// create some list we work with
$('body').html('<ul class="collection-list"></ul>');

// some array with string data
var collection = ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar'];

// here we store our jquery objects
var doms = [];

// for each item in the collection array we create a li
$.each(collection, function(index, value) {
    // imagine that the jquery part would return a reference/object which we push into our doms array
    doms.push($('ul.collection-list').append('<li class="item">' + value + '</li>'));
});

// we could now do different logic through our cached object
doms[2].val('new value');
doms[1].remove();
```

It could be that the example doesn't make any logical sense but please don't show me alternatives! I just want to use the presented technique. The example is just an example!

Comment: @TheZ: that is a good question..

Comment: As mentioned in the quotations jquery does NOT return an Object/reference to the create DOM. How do I "fix" this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your storing the entire `ul` element in the loop not the individual `li`s so do you mean;

```
$.each(collection, function(index, value) {
    doms.push($('<li class="item">' + value + '</li>'));
    $('ul.collection-list').append(doms[index]);
});

doms[2].html('new 3rd li value');
```

Comment: Yes I meant that. So did I understand right that I can't do this one line of code, instead I have to split?

Comment: @kyogron Don't worry so much about the number of lines of code. Yes, two lines will work.

Comment: You could use a selector but as TheZ said, 2 lines here is better imo; `doms.push($('ul.collection-list').append('<li class="item">' + value + '</li>').children(':last'));`

Comment: Thank you for the help :) Now I can unrender my backbone views peace for peace